# Symfony Doctrine instanceof PersistentCollection to App\Entity\

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity

Is it possible to return an array instead of PersistentCollection in Symfony 6.1.12?
There are relations:
Lessons ManyToOne Lecturers (lessons.lecturer_id = lecturers.id)
Lessons OneToMany LessonsTranslation (lessons.id = lessonsTranslation.lesson_id)

In class Lessons property:

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'lesson', targetEntity: LessonsTranslation::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $lessonTranslation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lessonTranslation = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    /**
     * @return Collection<int, LessonsTranslation>
     */
    public function getLessonTranslation(): Collection
    {
        return $this->lessonTranslation;
    }

    public function addLessonTranslation(LessonsTranslation $lessonTranslation): self
    {
        if (!$this->lessonTranslation->contains($lessonTranslation)) {
            $this->lessonTranslation->add($lessonTranslation);
            $lessonTranslation->setLesson($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLessonTranslation(LessonsTranslation $lessonTranslation): self
    {
        if ($this->lessonTranslation->removeElement($lessonTranslation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($lessonTranslation->getLesson() === $this) {
                $lessonTranslation->setLesson(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Now my query is looking that:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('lessons', 'lecturers', 'translation')
            ->from('App\Entity\Lessons', 'lessons')
            ->innerJoin('lessons.lecturer', 'lecturers')
            ->innerJoin('lessons.lessonTranslation', 'translation')
            ->where('lessons.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo')
            ->andWhere('translation.locale = :locale')
            ->setParameters([
                'dateFrom' => date('Y-m-') . '00', 
                'dateTo' => date('Y-m-', strtotime('+ 2 MONTH')) . '00',
                'locale' => $locale
                ])
            ->orderBy('lessons.date', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
```

It returns (with dd()) this array:

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => App\Entity\Lessons {#312 ▼
    -id: 8
    -date: DateTime @1682892000 {#315 ▶}
    -price: 150.0
    -lecturer: App\Entity\Lecturers {#555 ▶}
    -lessonTranslation: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#558 ▼
      #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#561 ▼
        -elements: & array:1 [▼
          0 => App\Entity\LessonsTranslation {#551 ▶}
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: App\Entity\Lessons {#312}
      -association: array:15 [ …15]
      -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#474 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "lesson"
      -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#296 …}
      -isDirty: false
    }
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Lessons {#541 ▶}
  2 => App\Entity\Lessons {#597 ▶}
  3 => App\Entity\Lessons {#619 ▶}
  4 => App\Entity\Lessons {#517 ▶}
  5 => App\Entity\Lessons {#610 ▶}
  6 => App\Entity\Lessons {#582 ▶}
  7 => App\Entity\Lessons {#577 ▶}
  8 => App\Entity\Lessons {#567 ▶}
  9 => App\Entity\Lessons {#566 ▶}
  10 => App\Entity\Lessons {#626 ▶}
  11 => App\Entity\Lessons {#627 ▶}
```

The best way is to return instance of App\Entity instead of ORM\PersistentCollection.

UPD: For now I've got the access to the field's properties in Twig by `{{ lesson.lessonTranslation.first.title }}`
But still it's not the best way I wish...

Comment: `lessonTranslation.toArray()` is the collection in array form.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The dumped array is already an array

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking simply use `$this->lessonTranslation->toArray()` (works on any `ArrayCollection`)